# Для чего нужен файл .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Для чего нужно использовать файл `.gitignore`, если можно просто выбрать файлы которые необходимо закоммитить, и сделать это?

Comment: Этот подход не масштабируется, уже при сотне файлов начнется геморрой.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Зачем добавлять в репозиторий (версионировать) файл .gitignore?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681285/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-gitignore)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Есть несколько задач, которые наиболее эффективно решаются с использованием файла `.gitignore`:

1. **Не мучаться с выбором нужных файлов для индексации** (которая `git add`).

   В большом проекте часто бывает много файлов, которые не подлежат версионированию. Свою лепту вносят редакторы и среды разработки, компиляторы, дебаггеры, прочие инструменты и сама операционная система. А ещё вам может быть удобно хранить какие-то промежуточные результаты в папке `tmp`.

   Настройка `.gitignore` позволяет не выискивать нужные файлы, а добавлять всё сразу или по крайней мере уточнять меньше. Соглашусь с [комментарием Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546520/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-gitignore-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/546565#comment697145_546520), подход "просто выбрать нужные" совершенно не масштабируется.
2. **Сделать локальный конфиг, который не будет затронут pull-ом**.

   Предположим, для работы вашего проекта нужен конфиг. Значения в нем зависимы от места выполнения, погоды и настроения разработчика.

   Вариант 1: сделать `local.conf` и вносить изменения при необходимости. Если вы его вдруг добавите и закоммитите, то у вас будут конфликты при pull/push. Или с пуллом к вам придёт чужой конфиг.

   Вариант 2: версионируемый `local.conf.example` и игнорируемый `local.conf`. В работе используется второй, для его формирования вручную или автоматически используется первый. Хорошо, удобно и не препятствует автоматизации. У меня так конфигурируются автотесты, запускаемые локально и на сервере интеграции.
3. **Защитить чувствительную информацию от случайного раскрытия**.

   Случается, что вы случайно добавили и закоммитили ключи или пароли от какого-нибудь облачного хранилища, например Amazon. А потом запушили это добро на GitHub. Что нужно делать в такой ситуации? Очень быстро бежать и менять все ключи и пароли, т.к. почти наверняка за ваш счёт уже майнятся биткойны.

   Если так уж необходимо хранить чувствительную информацию в папке проекта, то нужно положить её в под-папку, игнорируемую git.
4. **Быстро очищать проект от временных файлов**.

   Предположим, что вы пишете на компилируемом языке и при построении вашего проекта формируется множество промежуточных файлов (объектные, прекомпиляция, вот это всё). Перед каждой сборкой необходимо их удалять, чтобы в случае чего не прилинковать лишнее. Можно делать это вручную. Можно написать скрипт. А можно просто добавить их в `.gitignore` и делать так:

   ```
   git clean -fX
   ```

Comment: А как написать команду add что бы она не включала файлы в. gitignore? Пишу git add. И все равно все файлы добавляются.

Comment: Понял, файл должен быть в корне проекта

Answer (score 5):

1. игнорируемые файлы не будут перечисляться в выводе `git status`
2. игнорируемые файлы не будут добавляться в [индекс](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/intl/ru/ch07.html#_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0_git), даже если их имена подпадают под маску при вызове `git add маска`

> Для чего нужно использовать файл .gitignore

скорее, не «нужно», а «можно»: это просто удобно.

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас вдруг появится множество файлов, которые надо будет закоммитить, то будет неудобно их перечислять.

Поэтому проще указать перечень файлов, которые не надо отслеживать, а всё остальное считать рабочими файлами проекта и добавлять в полуавтоматическом режиме.

В случае, когда проект обрастает большим кол-вом логов, файлов автоматической сборки и прочим, легче их добавить по маске в файл `.gitignore` и не переживать, что они попадут куда-то дальше вашей рабочей директории.

Кроме того, можно создать один более-менее универсальный  файл `.gitignore` под свои нужды (под свои "типы" проектов) и копипастить его из проекта в проект без необходимости создания с нуля каждый раз.

*P.S. Автоматизация - наше всё! (^^,)*