# Зачем добавлять в репозиторий (версионировать) файл .gitignore?

Tags: git, github, gitignore

В нем же мы прописываем файлы, не нужные для просмотра стороннего посетителя вашего репозитория.... Пусть тогда и лежит себе на локалке.

Comment: Так там прописываются файлы, которые и будут git-ом игнорироваться и другие соответственно их не увидят, т.к. git с ними работать не будет.

Comment: Мне кажется, это другой вопрос. @Serg, вы же вроде бы понимаете, зачем нужен `.gitignore` и спрашиваете о том, зачем этот файл версионировать?

Comment: очень частый случай когда проект с зависимостями, например node_modules, они ни от кого из разработчиков не должны попадать в репозиторий

Comment: Потому что сторонний посетитель их тоже может создать, и при отправке вам патчей (в виде пулл-реквестов на гитхабе) они всё ещё нафиг не нужны, не создавать же каждому .gitignore заново

Answer (score 11):

Вопрос «[для чего нужен файл .gitignore?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546520/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-gitignore)» рассматривается отдельно.

Отвечаю на вопрос «для чего нужно версионировать `.gitignore`», то есть почему бы не заигнорить сам `.gitignore`.

> Пусть тогда и лежит себе на локалке

Есть такие причины добавить его в репозиторий:

- Этот файл нужен всем, кто работает над проектом. И у всех он будет примерно одинаковым. Так зачем делать лишнюю работу и составлять этот список каждому? Проще поделиться. (Исключение — когда вы хотите что-нибудь [игнорировать персонально и втайне от всех](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/448215/181472).)
- Это способ стандартизации работы команды. Например, в некой команде есть правило: логи приложения, скомпилированные бинарные файлы и [прочие артефакты сборки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/672235/181472) нельзя добавлять в репозиторий. Как проще всего обеспечить выполнение? Написать соответствующий `.gitignore` и закоммитить его в репозиторий.

Answer (score 6):

В том и дело что `.gitignore` нужен чтобы игнорировать файлы глобально. Если у вас есть какие-то файлы, которые не нужны вам *локально* - например, файлы IDE, - то следует использовать другие файлы:

- Для файлов, которые следует игнорировать у вас локально, но в пределах одного проекта, есть `.git/info/exclude` в том же формате. Вот его вы в самом деле не добавляете в Git.
- Кроме того, вы можете указать что какие-то файлы нужно игнорировать везде во всех проектах у вас на компьютере:

  ```
  git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
  ```

  [Примерное содержание такого файла.](https://gist.github.com/octocat/9257657)

Answer (score 0):

Не всегда есть возможность присутствовать (физически или удалённо подключаться), на локал хосте. бывает удобно продолжить разработку оперативно на любом пк.

Comment: Согласен, и это частный случай «Этот файл нужен всем, кто работает над проектом».