# Создание .gitignore в intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea, gitignore

Не могу создать `.gitignore`. Не понимаю, что делаю не так. Сам файл создается, но он не читается как файл гита. Проект скопировал со своего репозитория на гитхабе, сейчас работаю не на своем компе, но `git` установлен и работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вы определили что он "не читается как файл гита" и что под этим имеете в виду? Инструкции в нём не применяются к репозиторию или просто он не подсвечен как-то? Может вам просто какой-то плагин надо в IDE добавить для `gitignore`-a?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Во-первых, он не подсвечен иконкой гита, а во-вторых, он действительно не выполняет своих функций и не игнорирует файлы в коммите.

Comment: Игнорирование работает только для новых добавленных файлов. Для ранее добавленных работать не будет до их прямого удаления из индекса. Попробуйте добавить исключение и файл под него подходящий

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Дело в том, что на моем компе этот файл был, просто в самом gitignore он был и прописан, по этому и не попал на гитхаб. Получается, я не могу создать уже в этом проекте еще один gitignore?

Comment: Я вас не понял.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб В этом проекте уже добавлял gitignore, но не добавлял его в коммит. Сейчас работаю с другого компа и скопировал себе проект. Но вот файл gitignore создать почему-то не выходит.

Comment: у вас **gitignore** не закомичен в репозиторий?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да, незакомичен

Comment: @Pro100Denysko пока не закомитете работать не будет

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, насколько я помню коммитить не надо для активации. Я думаю тут дело в том, что уже добавленные в индекс файлы не игнорятся, хотя ТС этого ожидает)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не правильно помните.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, только что сделал `git init` в папке где есть папка `A` и `.gitignore` без `A`. `git status` выдаёт папку `A` как не добавленную в индекс. Добавил `A` в `.gitignore` - и папка исчезла из списка недобавленных файлов. При этом ещё ни одного коммита нет в репе, как и добавленных в индекс файлов.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вы правы. это я не правильно помню.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> не читается как файл гита... не подсвечен иконкой гита

Нет такой сущности как «файл гита». Иконка на файле с именем `.gitignore` появляется только в вашей среде разработки от IntelliJ, если в ней установлен плагин [.ignore](http://ignore.hsz.mobi/). Вероятно, на одной рабочей машине этот плагин установлен, а на другой — нет (оказалось, что он был установлен, но [не работал](https://github.com/hsz/idea-gitignore/issues/408)).

Сама программа git всегда читает содержимое этого файла, если находит его. Если при этом она, как вы пишете, «не выполняет своих функций и не игнорирует файлы в коммите», то это потому, что файлы добавлены в индекс до того, как вы создали файл `.gitignore`. [Читайте, как это исправить.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432895/181472)

Файл `.gitignore` учитывается сразу, как только он появился в рабочей области проекта. Но, как и любой другой значимый файл, [его желательно версионировать (сохранять в коммите)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681285/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-gitignore).

> файл gitignore создать почему-то не выходит

Это самый обычный файл в файловой системе. Если в данной директории ещё нет файла с таким именем, то его можно создать. В Windows могут быть сложности с тем, чтобы начать имя файла с точки — читайте [как создать файл .gitignore в Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438367/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-gitignore-%d0%b2-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, проблема с последней Intellij
https://github.com/hsz/idea-gitignore/issues/408

Comment: Проблема не с IDEA, а с плагином. Но он вообще-то не обязателен, файл создать можно и без него, а на фактическое игнорирование файлов он вообще не влияет. )