# Удаление/отключение измененных файлов

Tags: git

Иногда приходится генерировать, какие-то временные файлы(например статику на сайте), которые отображаются красным цветом при вызове команды `git status`. Как можно удалить/отключить отслеживание этих файлов, чтобы `git status` не выдавал их совсем?

Comment: Добавить в .gitignore?

Comment: Использовать `.gitignore`

Comment: Нельзя какой-то командой это сделать?

Comment: Как уже писали, нужно использовать gitignore, подробнее о нем https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546520/Для-чего-нужен-файл-gitignore

Comment: а чем вас не устраивает через gitignore?

Comment: с вима сложно выйти:)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Для чего нужен файл .gitignore?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546520/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-gitignore)

Comment: Прочитать документацию на `git status`?

Answer (score 2):

Использовать глобальный файл .gitignore в вашем проекте и в него монжо включить файлы/папки, которые вы хотите игнорировать от гита.

[Ссылка](https://tyapk.ru/blog/post/gitignore)

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore ссылка на официальную документацию

Comment: И почему часто забывают о втором варианте, зачастую более подходящем: использовать `.git\into\exclude`. Удобен тем, что изменения в нём в отличие от .gitignore не светятся и не бесят. Именно для случая когда не хочется временные файлы или папки коммитить в gitignore.