# Как подготовить проект к публикации на github JS

Tags: javascript

Готовый проект весит очень много, что-бы скинуть вес люди удаляют файлы модулей, потом их можно установить через npm install (Остаются в package.json), хочу сделать так-же но не знаю как

Comment: ну если node_modules весит много, в чем проблема удалить папку?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/546520/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-gitignore

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать файл `.gitignore` в папке с проектом
2. В созданный файл `.gitignore` написать:

```
node_modules/
```

Когда будете пушить в git, те файлы/папки, которые вы написали в `.gitignore` не будут добавляться